# Is "\*" the same as "*" in scala？

Tags: scala

I see a piece of code as

```
def poly(x: Int): Int = x\*x - 2\*x +1
```

the symbol `\*` confused me. It seems that this `\*` works like multiply, i.e. `*`,  but why there is a `\` ahead of `*`? Is `\*` the same as `*`?

Comment: I don't think `\*` is even valid syntax? unless it is defined as a custom method like `def \*(x: Int) = x * x` can you please post where did you see that?

Comment: it's not the valid syntax can you please tell me where have you seen such code?

Comment: @prayagupd: "I don't think `\*` is even valid syntax?" – Yes, it *is* valid syntax. It is a valid identifier, just like `foo` or `bar` or `???` or `*`. "unless it is defined as a custom method like `def \*(x: Int) = x * x`" – This makes no sense. If it *isn't* valid syntax (like you claim), then you couldn't define a method with that name. If you *could* define a method with that name, then it obviously must be valid syntax. It cannot be both invalid syntax and a valid method name, that statement is contradictory.

Comment: @RamanMishra: It *is* valid syntax. It is a valid method name just like `foo` or `bar` or `???` or `*`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag yes i agree its a valid method name if defined and in the question i don't see any user defined method name /*.

Comment: @RamanMishra: "yes i agree its a valid method name if defined" – No. It is a valid method name *period*. Whether an identifier is valid or not is given by the rules for valid identifiers in the language specification and has nothing to do with being defined or not. In fact, if an identifier were only valid when it is defined, then you could never define it because it wouldn't be a valid identifier! "i don't see any user defined method name /*" – That is irrelevant. Whether or not an identifier is valid has nothing to do with whether it is defined or not. It either is valid or it isn't. …

Comment: … `\*` is a valid identifier in Scala because the rules for valid identifiers in Scala say that it is. `hello!` is *not* a valid identifier in Scala because the rules for valid identifiers in Scala say that it isn't. (In particular, it violates the rule that alphanumeric characters and operator characters must be separated with `_`.) And you can't make it a valid identifier by defining it, because you can't define it, because it isn't a valid identifier.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't exist in vanilla Scala. It would be possible to define `\*` as a method in an implicit class:

```
implicit class IntOps(x: Int) {
  def \*(y: Int) = x * y
}
```

Which can be used in the same way as you're seeing: `6 \* 7`

But to use this new method `\*` in your code, the implicit class must be in scope or imported.

However, I suspect that none of the above is applicable here. It could be the case that there's just an error in displaying the code which instead should read:

`def poly(x: Int): Int = x*x - 2*x +1`

Answer (score 0):

> I see a piece of code as
>
> ```
> def poly(x: Int): Int = x\*x - 2\*x +1
> ```
>
> the symbol `\*` confused me. It seems that this `\*` works like multiply, i.e. `*`,  but why there is a `\` ahead of `*`?

That is simply the name of the method. `\*` is just as valid as a method name as `*` or `foo` or `bar` or `???`. It's just a method like any other method.

> Is `\*` the same as `*`?

No, `\*` is `\*` and `*` is `*`. They are different methods, just like `foo` and `bar` are different methods.